# Portable plugins with CMake

Tags: macos, cmake, clang, shared-libraries, dlopen

I am trying to find a portable way of generating modules (dlopen, dlsym, dlerror, dlclose) with CMake.
The whole source code of my attempt is located [here](https://github.com/cdoucet/forexample/tree/master/dlopen).
Here is the CMake script:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(dlopen_example CXX)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(main main.cpp print_ref.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(main dl)

ADD_LIBRARY(module MODULE module.cpp)

IF(APPLE)
  SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(module PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-undefined dynamic_lookup")
ENDIF(APPLE)
```

As you may remark, I have to add

```
-undefined dynamic_lookup
```

to the set of link flags on Mac OSX (clang compiler). Indeed, while there is no problem on Linux Ubuntu, I get an error message on Mac OSX if I do not add this flag and let CMake handle flags with the line

```
ADD_LIBRARY(module MODULE module.cpp)
```

The error message I get is the following:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "print_ref()", referenced from:
>   _module in module.cpp.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am surprised that the MODULE option of ADD_LIBRARY does not handle such a flag.Is there a portable solution to this problem with CMake?

Comment: Looks like this solution is most portable. If you create several modules, instead of setting LINK_FLAGS property for every of them, you may set  variable [CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS.html) once.

Comment: Thank you for the tip Tsyvarev! Bad news otherwise. I wonder wether it is a bug in CMake or not.